# Batch script to create folder with date and subfolders

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, files-folders

So I've managed to make a script that creates a folder with a date with the following:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined fulldate set fulldate=%%i
set year=%fulldate:~2,2%
set month=%fulldate:~4,2%
set day=%fulldate:~6,2%
set foldername=%day%.%month%.%year%
md %foldername%
```

Now, I need the script to create 5 subfolders within each day. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How should the 5 subfolders be named?

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined fulldate set fulldate=%%i
set year=%fulldate:~2,2%
set month=%fulldate:~4,2%
set day=%fulldate:~6,2%
set foldername=%day%.%month%.%year%
md %foldername%\Subfolder01
md %foldername%\Subfolder02
md %foldername%\Subfolder03
md %foldername%\Subfolder04
md %foldername%\Subfolder05
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For each folder you've created by this script, call the below script for that.

```
Foreach($folder in Get-Content "C:\Scripts\data.txt")
{
   New-Item "C:\Scripts\$folder" -ItemType directory
}
```

**Here data.txt is any file or simply an empty file present in the parent folder.**

*I checked this and it worked for me perfectly as you want.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```bat
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*delims^=^= %%i in (`wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year /value^|find "="
   `)do if /i "%%~i" == "Year" (set "_%%~i=%%~j")else if %%~j lss 10 (set "_%%~i=0%%~j")else set "_%%~i=%%~j"

for %%i in ("Folder 1","Folder 2","Folder 3","Folder 4","Folder 5")do <con: md "%_Day%.%_Month%.%_Year%\%%~i"
```

---

Or also creating all folders directly in the same `mkdir` command/line

```bat
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*delims^=^= %%i in (`wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year /value^|find "="
   `)do if /i "%%~i" == "Year" (set "_%%~i=%%~j")else if %%~j lss 10 (set "_%%~i=0%%~j")else set "_%%~i=%%~j"

mkdir ".\%_Day%.%_Month%.%_Year%" && <con: pushd ".\%_Day%.%_Month%.%_Year%\"
mkdir ".\Folder 1" ".\Folder 2" ".\Folder 3" ".\Folder 4" ".\Folder 5" & popd
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`Wmic /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [`MkDir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Variable and Substring Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [`if() else if() else ()` Conditionally perform a command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

---